# Copy paste gulp node_modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js, gulp

I'm using Gulp for my project. I used the path `C:\Users\senthil\Desktop\angular` for installing gulp. But it got installed on `C:\Users\senthil`. So I copied the folder and pasted it in my desired path, with `gulp.js` file. Once I run the command `gulp`, it shows an error

> gulp is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or bath file

Do copy, paste of `node_modules` is wrong?

Comment: The installer possibly added `C:\Users\senthil` to your `PATH` environment variable. If that's the case, you'll have to update that to your new location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the current working directory using `cd` command to your node project. Install node modules there.

Gulp module should be installed globally. Use the following command to do so:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Now `gulp` command will be available anywhere in command prompt

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I found that by default it got installed in the directory where I installed first. I deleted that one and re-install in the desired path. It came out well.